# MVC view prevent repeating html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, view

I have some HTML which needs to be included in different parts of the view.

```
<img class="class"
     data-Person-id="@Model.PersonId.ToString()"
     onClick="functionCall(this)"
     src="~/Images/SomeImage.gif" />
```

As the question states the exact same code needs to be included in different parts of the view and even in different `Partial Views` which contains the same `model`. Though it isn't the biggest problem in the world, I don't like repeating code which OO limits doing.

Just wondering if there is a technique or method to prevent copying and pasting the code?

(I have everything in the model and the controller so I wouldn't like to be changing this code, however if it needs to happen, I am happy to change it)

Comment: You could add this html in its own shared partial view, then just call @Html.Partial("_ImageView", Model.PersonId) or create an HTML Helper

Comment: @AshleyMedway thanks, the partial view approach is the correct way. If you make it into an answer, I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move your HTML to a shared partial view that accepts your Model

```
@model MyModel

<img class="class"
     data-Person-id="@Model.PersonId.ToString()"
     onClick="functionCall(this)"
     src="~/Images/SomeImage.gif" />
```

Then call the partial view like this `@Html.Partial("_ImageView", Model)`